# How to use firebase stored vidoes in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have firebase stored video link. I can download the video. But I don't know how to use to show the video in reactjs app. Can you help me?

Here is my code. how can I use that video url?

```
const [filedata, setFileData] = useState([]);
 
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

const submitHanlder = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
   const file = e.target[0].files[0];
   console.log(file)
   fileUpload(file);
}

const fileUpload = (file) => {
     if(!file) return;

     const storageRef =ref(storage, `/files/${file.name}`);

     const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef,file);
     uploadTask.on("state_changed",(snapshot) => {
       const prog = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);

        setProgress(prog);
     },(err)=> console.log(err),() => {
       getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(url => console.log(url));
     })
}
```

Comment: Since you already call `getDownloadURL`, did you try showing that URL in an `img`? https://www.google.com/search?q=react+show+image+from+url

Comment: I can get to use images. And also I can get download the video from the firebase URL. but I cannot use it. this is the firebase video link : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fileuploads-demo.appspot.com/o/files%2Fvlc-record-2020-11-19-12h53m12s-www.1TamilMV.live-.ts?alt=media&token=47398074-d772-42cb-9220-f21ee5575e47      .I think Now I figure out the problem. I'm not sure. this file is .ts video format. I can get use other format like mp4. If i'm right browser does not support this format. or any other ways to use??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player
Example usage below

```
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />
```